# Какими способами можно организовать обработку действий пользователя в Electron с полным отделением логики и разметки?

Tags: node.js, electron

В этом [видеоуроке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU) по Electron.js обработка действий пользователя осуществляется прямо в html-файле (просто хочу показать в целом подход; вчитываться в код не нужно):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Shopping list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a class="brand-logo center">Shopping list</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul></ul>

  <script>

    const Electron = require('electron');
    const { ipcRenderer } = Electron;
    const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

    ipcRenderer.on('item:add', (event, item) => {

      ul.className = 'collection';

      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.className = 'collection-item';

      const itemText = document.createTextNode(item);
      li.appendChild(itemText);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('item:clear', () => {

      ul.innerHTML = '';

      if (ul.children.length === 0) {
        ul.className = '';
      }
    });

    ul.addEventListener('dblclick', removeItem);

    function removeItem(event) {

      event.target.remove();

      if (ul.children.length === 0) {
        ul.className = '';
      }
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вероятно, это нормально для первого урока по Electron, но в целом наличие логики в HTML-файле - это плохо. Какой же способ обработки событий пользователя следует выбрать вместо того, который был предложен в уроке? Подойдёт ли "стандартный" подход ненавязчивого JavaScrit-а, при котором сначала полностью рендеристся DOM, а потом JavaScript (нативно или через jQuery) начинает вмешиваться в DOM? Но если будет один JavaScript-файл на страницу, то как же тогда передавать состояние приложения между страницами?